# jq return a json array in a very specifique way

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I have this Json ( is a test database, no data is true here )

```
{
  "pguid": "4EA979A2-E578-4DA3-89DB-24082F3092AA",
  "lastEnrollTguid": "EA98B161-04D3-4F0A-920A-58DBFF3C2274",
  "timestamp": 1016086888000,
  "keys": [
    {
      "id": "gr",
      "value": "1907971"
    }
  ],
  "biographics": [
    {
      "id": "localNascimento",
      "value": "JOINVILLE SC"
    },
    {
      "id": "dataNascimento",
      "value": "1859-03-08"
    },
    {
      "id": "mae",
      "value": "ANTA MARCIA PINHEAD"
    },
    {
      "id": "nome",
      "value": "MIR PINHEAD"
    }
  ],
  "biometric": [
    {
      "source": "ORIGINAL",
      "type": "FACE",
      "format": "JPEG",
      "properties": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "resolution": 500,
        "ratio": 0,
        "matcherId": 0,
        "extractorId": 0
      },
      "index": 10,
      "content": "5215421547"
    }
  ],
  "labels": [
    "SC",
    "CIVIL",
    "MASCULINO",
    "JOINVILLE"
  ],
  "history": {
    "events": [
      {
        "type": "ENROLL",
        "tguid": "3C1B0D1F-9143-4C24-A351-E88A19317AC9",
        "timestamp": 1014086658288
      },
      {
        "type": "UPDATE",
        "tguid": "EA98B161-04D3-4F0A-920A-58DBFF3C2274",
        "timestamp": 1016786888028
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to retrive only de tguid in history array, and if exist a way to do this, use de index of the array to acomplish that.

Here I tryed to acomplish that ( and miserable failed in that )
example ( and it do not work ):

```
jq  '.[].history.events.tguid[1]' /tmp/teste.json
```

I want to retrieve the pguid in a index to work with that.
Someone have any ideas?

Comment: It seems obvious that `tguid` is not an array.

Comment: If you want to make an array named `tguid`: `jq  '{ "tguid": [.history.events[].tguid] }' /tmp/teste.json`. Then you can address this array as `.tguid[1]` like this: `jq  '{ "tguid": [.history.events[].tguid] } | .tguid[1]'`

Comment: In accordance with the [mcve] guidelines, please show the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tnks everyone

```
jq  '.[].history.events | .[0].tguid' /tmp/teste1.json
```

Comment: To other answer reviewers: this is actually different from other answer and comments, so it is actually the answer to this question which should stay on this site.

Comment: @Dominique I need wait 20 hours to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
jq  '.history.events | .[1].tguid' /tmp/teste.json
```

Comment: tnks for your post. I tried and I recived "null" 

#jq  '.history.events | .[1].tguid' /tmp/teste.json
#null